# How do I install a specific version of bitcoin-core

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

I need to run bitcoind version 0.17, however the latest available version is 0.18, if I follow the instructions from this [link](https://linuxhint.com/install-bitcoin-core-ubuntu/) it installs the latest version.

The below links lists the packages for the version I need however I am not sure how to use it, I mean how to install it on my local machine as `apt-get install` command does automatically.

https://bitcoincore.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.17.1/

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just unzip the file and run the binary. Typically the binaries `bitcoind` and `bitcoin-cli`, etc. are stored in the `/usr/local/bin`, `man` folder in the `/usr/local/man`, etc. so that it is in your machine's `PATH` environment variable and can be run from anywhere.

If you choose to download the source code, you can install by following instructions here (for Unix): [Build Unix](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md)

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

But you may need to install dependencies. See [Linux Distribution Specific Instructions](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md#linux-distribution-specific-instructions)

Comment: If I plant to run from binaries, how do I set the path so bitcoin-cli can be run from anywhere, typically how it behaves when installed from apt-get?

Answer (score 3):

If you're building from source, you can select a specific version as follows:

First, review the build requirements, dependencies, and instructions for your OS:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/doc

Once that is done, use git to pull the source code and select a branch:

```
## clone the bitcoin repository
$ git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git

## change folders
$ cd bitcoin

## check which versions are available
$ git tag

## find your desired version in the list, and then 'checkout'
$ git checkout v0.x.x

## now you can build:
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ ./make
$ sudo make install
```

Once you have finished the install and booted up bitcoind, you can confirm the correct version of the client and daemon are running:

`bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo`

`bitcoind --version`